# How to Resize an element using Selenium through Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

I am trying to automate the "realizable concept"(Drag and Drop) in Selenium through the link -http://jqueryui.com/resizable/.
I am getting the error:

```
invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[contains(@class.'demo-frame')].
```

Could you please let me know if there is any other way of representing the XPATH?
Below is my code for the same. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ResizeExample {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testToResizeElement() {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("http://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector(".demo-frame")));
        WebElement resizeableElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-se.ui-icon.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"));
        resize(resizeableElement, 50, 50);
    }

    public void resize(WebElement elementToResize, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        try {
            if (elementToResize.isDisplayed()) {
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.clickAndHold(elementToResize).moveByOffset(xOffset, yOffset).release().build().perform();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Element was not displayed to drag");
            }
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Element with " + elementToResize + "is not attached to the page document "  + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element " + elementToResize + " was not found in DOM " + e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to resize" + elementToResize + " - " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First thing xpath throwing error is due to the "@class**.**'demo-frame'. That "." should be "," and you don't have a div with that class, it's the iframe which had that class.

Second:
resizeableElement element is in a iframe so you have to switch to frame before checking if resizeableElement element exist and interact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automate the *realizable concept(Drag and Drop)* with in the webpage http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ through *Selenium* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resizable/");
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='demo-frame']")));
  WebElement  target = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se']")));
  //dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset) //status: WORKS
  new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(target, 50, 50).build().perform();
  System.out.println("Resizing of element Completed");
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Resizing of element Completed
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: jQuery_resizable]

Comment: Thank you soo much for guiding and providing the right solution for my problem.